# improper integral and its limit in infty

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, improper-integrals

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DU5GR.png)

I have trouble solving this problem for few hours...

1. For (a), I was just trying with the range of integration by $\int_a^b$ where a,b is large enough. Since h(b)-h(a) $\leq \int^b_a H(t) \rightarrow 0$, it is concluded that h has limit in inf (Cauchy seq). Then h(t) should be zero by assumption.

Is it clear? or is there another way to make this proof more neatly?

+I think the inequality part in my proof does not make sense as it is not accompanied with $||$, (absolute value).

2. For (b) and (c), my idea was MVT, and integration by parts... but I couldn't make it.

Comment: "Is it clear?" --- "it is concluded that h has limit in inf (Cauchy seq)." --- No.

Comment: $h(b) - h(a) = \int_a^b h'(t)\, dt \le  \int_a^b H(t)\, dt$, so that inequality itself is correct. However, the conclusion you draw from this does not follow from that inequality.